# Algorithm to find a facet of a polyhedron given the vertices?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes

I have a set of points $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_N\}$ on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$ ($N>d\ge 3$). What is an algorithm to find any facet of the polyhedron whose vertices are $X$?

The set $X$ has some features that may be helpful:

- It is highly symmetric in the sense that for each pair $x,x'\in X$ there is an isometry that maps $X$ to itself while mapping $x\to x'$.  ($X$ "looks the same" from the vantage of any point in the set.) For this reason it is sufficient for me to find any facet; by symmetry the others will look the same.
- I can efficiently enumerate the points closest to any given $x\in X$.

Note, I am *not* looking for a software tool. The set $X$ is a theoretical construct and I wish to use my knowledge about $X$ and some facet-finding procedure TBD to determine the facet geometry analytically.  An example of the *kind* of answer I am looking for might be something like "1. Pick any vertex.  2. Find one of its nearest neighbors.  3.  Find one of that vertex's nearest neighbors ... "

Comment: Your first bullet point says that the polyhedron is vertex-transitive, but note that this does not imply facet-transitivity. Consider for example in $\mathbb{R}^3$ a cube flattened in one dimension. All vertices look the same but the facets do not.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen  That's true.  In my case I think it is also facet-transitive, but that's probably not critical to the question I'm asking.

Comment: Is the polytope simple? Then there is an algorithmic way to reconstruct the faces from the edges, at least.

Comment: For $d=3$, I think it is enough to start with a vertex $x$, choose a vertex $y$ which maximizes $x\cdot y$, choose a vertex $z$ which maximizes $(x+y)\cdot z$, and then take all the vertices coplanar with $x,y,z$. But I have not written down a proof and I am not sure how well this generalizes to higher dimensions.

Comment: @SamHopkins  I don't know whether it is simple.  Also, I don't have the edges, just the vertices.

Comment: @MattF.  Yes, something along those lines seems reasonable and would be a nice answer -- if it is actually correct ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by Matt F's response, I figured out a solution (I think). Intuitively, a procedure that will find *some* facet starting from a given vertex $x_1$ is the following:  Start with a hyperplane containing the point $x_1$ and orthogonal to the vector $x_1$. Then tilt the hyperplane in some direction until it intersects another vertex.  Using those two vertices as pivot points, tilt the hyperplane in some other direction until it intersects a third vertex, and so on until you have $d$ linearly independent vertices.

More formally, let $x_i$ denote the vertex selected in iteration $i$ and let $u_i$ denote a vector in the span of $x_1,...,x_i$ and orthogonal to the face defined by these vertices. "Tilting the hyperplane" is achieved by adding to $u_i$ any vector orthogonal to $x_1,\ldots,x_i$.

Given an initial vertex $x_1$, start by taking $u_1 = x_1$.  Then to find $x_{i+1}$ and $u_{i+1}$,

1. Define
   $$
   \lambda_i(x) = \frac{1 - x \cdot u_i}{||\Pi_i x||}
   $$
   where $\Pi_i$ is the projector onto the subspace orthogonal to $x_1,\ldots,x_i$.
2. Take
   $$
   x_{i+1} = \arg \min_{x\in X} \lambda_i(x) \\
   u_{i+1} = u_i + \lambda_i(x_i) \frac{\Pi_i x_i}{||\Pi_i x_i||}
   $$

After $d$ iterations, one obtains $d$ linearly independent vertices $F = \{x_1,\ldots,x_d\}$.  It can be shown inductively that $u_d \cdot x_1 = \cdots = u_d \cdot x_d = 1$ and $u_d \cdot x < 1$ for all $x\in X - F$.  Thus $F$ defines a facet.

Comment: You may be missing  the possibility of hitting more than one vertex at the same time when you tilt the hyperplane. Eg this can happen in 3-d whenever the faces have more than 3 vertices.

Answer (score 1):

For historical record, I believe the solution is called Polytope Faces Pursuit (M. D. Plumbley, “Recovery of Sparse Representations by Polytope Faces Pursuit,” in Independent Component Analysis and Blind Signal Separation, Lecture Notes in Computer Science. Berlin, Heidelberg: Springer, 2006, pp. 206–213. doi: 10.1007/11679363_26.)  The basic idea is to search for an extremal point (vertex) of the dual polytope using constrained optimization, starting from the origin. I believe this is related to the approach I postulated above, but more elegant and more correct.